# Angular Scope inside script

Tags: javascript, angularjs, javascript-framework

Can we use the angular variables defined in scope inside script tag like below.

HTML CODE:

```
<div ng-controller="AngularCtrl">
 <script>
  alert($scope.user_name);
 </script>
</div>
```

JS CODE:

```
function AngularCtrl($scope){
 $scope.user_name = 'John';
}
```

I just get '$scope is not defined'. Can someone help me with what i am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No you can't. `$scope` is only defined *inside* Angular, i.e. within your `AngularCtrl`-function. There are ways to get access to angular scopes from the outside, but that's usually bad practice and a sign that you're not using Angular correctly.

A more angulariffic way to do what you're trying is to make the alerting a part of the controller-logic:

```
function AngularCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.user_name = 'John';

    $scope.sayHi = function(){
        alert('Hi ' + $scope.user_name);
    }
}
```

You can then use a variety of angular-techniques ([Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/sveinatle/WqSGR/1)) to call that `sayHi()` function. Some examples:

#### In response to a click

```
<div ng-click="sayHi()">Demo clickable - Please click me</div>
```

#### Automatically once when a given element is created/initialized

```
<div ng-init="sayHi()">Demo ng-init</div>
```

#### Directly from the controller when it is initialized

```
function AngularCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.user_name = 'John';

    $scope.sayHi = function(){
        alert('Hi ' + $scope.user_name);
    }

    // Call it
    $scope.sayHi();
}
```

Hopefully these examples are inspiring, but what you really should do depends on what you are really trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks Very much Supr! My problem here is I have a DOM that is not present when page is loaded. The DOM is loaded only on click of specific action. But the problem is the angular code inside that DOM is not compiled. so Is there a way to do $compile(jQuery("#DOM_ID")) when the DOM is loaded? Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, though you should probably create a directive for it. See the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile) and [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/sveinatle/qFmP8/). Notice that a scope is applied to the return value of the compilation, effectively `var compiled=$compile(element.contents()); compiled($scope);`.

Comment: Note that there is already [a built-in include directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngInclude) in Angular which might do what you want. The example there responds to changes in a drop down, though you could easily adjust it to respond to a click event.

Comment: How can one access the element that calls that function on init? Is there a `this`?

Comment: @Andy, I don't know, and technically you shouldn't. Controllers shouldn't be dealing with the DOM/elements. If you need to interact with the element then that's a sign that you actually need to make a suitable directive. That will make it easier to reuse as well.

Comment: thanks – I'd like an inline-script in HTML, but I can't even access properties of the scope, so the other way doesn't work either. For my case a directive seems quite an overkill.

Comment: @Andy What are you trying to accomplish? Perhaps it would be a suitable question to post :)

Comment: I would like the bad-practice example. I have a third party script that I'd like to bind some values to.

Comment: @MrBoJangles, `scope = angular.element('body').scope()` will get you the scope "at" the `body` element. Replace `'body'` with an appropriate selector for other scopes. Remember to make sure a digest is triggered after modifying a scope from the outside -- that can be done by performing the modifications in a callback to `scope.$apply`, e.g. `scope.$apply(function(){scope.test = "hello";});`. Note that this is for Angular 1.x. I don't know if it applies to Angular 2.x.

Comment: Of course you can also accomplish something similar by just saving a reference to the scope like `window.myscope = $scope` or `thridparty.myscope = $scope` from inside a controller.

Comment: Thanks, @Supr. For what it's worth, our project is kind of a razor/angular hybrid and my solution was to simply use razor bindings. Sometimes, you just gotta bind on the server. I would be curious as to how one would take care of this particular issue in a purely angular SPA. The issue was that a 3rd party script needed to be executed at load time with values that existed at load time. The script was designed by PHP guys with an assumption of PHP-style server-side binding.