# Call Angular Controller in JS Script

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i need to call angular function (=controller) in JS fuction on .jsp .
I had try lot of possiblities but nothing run.

I have .jsp file with my HTML and JS, and i have angular function in app.js.

```js
/* 
** app.js
*/

$scope.addEvent = function(element, byTypeAdd) {
     if ($scope.element && $scope.byTypeAdd){
      $scope.events.push({ name : $scope.element, type : $scope.byTypeAdd });
      $scope.element = '';
     };
    }
```

```html
<script>
  function fewValues() {
    var valueId = 1;
    var valueType = "Type 1";
    
    
    /*Here i want to use addEvent*/
    
  }
```

Comment: what is it you are trying to do exactly? why would you want to call a controller? can we see some code

Comment: place the app.js file before your js function.

Comment: Follow up question: *why does my view not get updated*. No really, don't do stuff like that. Use a service to bind your controllers or code in general together.

Comment: I don't want really call a controller but this function. All angular between div run in my .jsp but this script is under all div.

Comment: What I want to say is that if you call your angular-code from *the outside* nothing will work as expected. Because angular will not recognize that it should check for changes. If you go this path, you will run into other problems. So I'd advice to against even beginning to go in that direction.

Comment: Thanks Yoshi, i have found the answer in this post too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13836765/angular-scope-inside-script

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer then, so that other people can profit from it. You can of course also accept it, nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't find a good solution for my problem, so i am switch to JQuery and it run.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you make your **addEvent** method a service and do the same thing through [angular.injector](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.injector)

Following is the example from above document

```
var $div = $('<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">{{content.label}}</div>');
$(document.body).append($div);

angular.element(document).injector().invoke(function($compile) {
  var scope = angular.element($div).scope();
  $compile($div)(scope);
});
```